# how to differentiate click in custom view?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I created a class that extends the `view` Class. In `onDraw` it draws a hexagon. After adding the view to my layout it looks like in the picture: [hexagon created by view-class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3u0d.png).

Now I want to set an `onClickListener` on the tile so that it reacts only if I touch the hexagonal shape. The problem is, that the view (as it is rectangular) also reacts when I click/ touch on the edges (marked with blue) which is a problem if I place multiple views next to each other.

Is it possible to make **only the hexagonal** shape sensible for the `onClickListener`?

Comment: I've updated the question . may be this is what you are trying to say

Comment: You have to override `onTouchEvent` and return true or false depending on whether the point is in the hexagon area

Comment: well for that insite your on touch you need to see the positon of touch through motionevent and calculate accordingily